# method not getting called inside rest api

Tags: apex, rest-api, scheduled-apex, schedule

I have created two rest API methods in the schedulable class when I called in the execute function my first method is called and worked fine in my First response my second method is not triggered. how would I invoke the second function to be called? Thanks in Advance.

```
global class BCIScheduler implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {
        
        AMethod();
    }
    
    
    
    public  void AMethod()
    {
        List<object> AList = new List<object>();
        try
        {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            System.debug('Roles Entered: '+ roles);
            request.setEndpoint('http://api.json.com/rest/a.json?Fields='+Fields);
            request.setMethod('GET');
            request.setTimeout(120000);
            request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); 
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200)
            {
                
                List<object> Ajson = (List<object>) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<AClass>.class);
                AList.addAll(Ajson);
                
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception exp){                     
            system.debug(exp.getMessage()+ exp.getLineNumber());
            
        }
        
    }
}


if(AList.size()>0)
{
    
    batch_upsert upst = new batch_upsert(AList);
    database.executeBatch(upst,100);
    BMethod();
}





}

public  void BMethod()
{
    
    try
    {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        System.debug('Roles Entered: '+ roles);
        request.setEndpoint('http://api.json.com/rest/b.json?Fields='+Fields);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setTimeout(120000);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); 
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            
            List<object> Bjson = (List<object>) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<Bclass>.class);
            BList.addAll(Bjson);
            
        }
        
    }
    catch(Exception exp){                     
        system.debug(exp.getMessage()+ exp.getLineNumber());
        
    }
    
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is being called. It's throwing an exception that you cannot see because you have suppressed all exceptions. The exception being thrown is

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

because you performed a DML-equivalent operation (enqueueing a batch) prior to performing a callout in method B.

You should never use this structure:

```
    catch(Exception exp){                     
        system.debug(exp.getMessage()+ exp.getLineNumber());
        
    }
```

Exceptions happen for a reason. Don't swallow and hide them. Silent failures produce terrible code that is very difficult to debug.

You can solve this problem by restructuring your code to enqueue batch classes only *after* you have made all of the callouts you need.

Comment: Hi @David Reed can you provide some example ?

Comment: If you search SFSE for "You have uncommitted work pending" you will find dozens of examples of people working with this issue.